# Astra Theme Mobile Menu Pushes Content Downward

Tags: mobile, menu, wordpress-theme-astra

When I tap on the the menu on a mobile device (phone), the menu pushes the content downward. How would I get this so that tapping on the menu just drops down and overlaps the content rather than pushing it downward?